# Maze solver algorithm for pygame maze?

Tags: python, algorithm, pygame, generator, maze

For a project, I have used the pygame module in Python to create a maze generator (Python version 3.3.5). I have already added user control to the maze, and I tried to get it so that if the user is stuck, he/she presses the escape key and the maze solves itself and displays a trail of pink to hep the user. I tried this by randomly choosing a direction, not allowing it to backtrack itself, and to restart if stuck. It is a little buggy (sometimes doesn't work), and takes too long for bigger mazes. Could someone help me by adding a maze solver that actually is smart, and can work for larger mazes? Thanks for any help.

```
import pygame
import time
import random

#Set colors.
BLACK   =(0,0,0)
WHITE   =(255,255,255)
RED     =(255,0,0)
GREEN   =(0,255,0)
BLUE    =(0,0,255)
PURPLE  =(128,0,128)
LRED    =(255,128,128)

pygame.init()

#Smallest space: 5.
space=10

length=80
width=80

sizex=200+length*space
sizey=200+width*space

#Set size.
size=(sizex, sizey)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Make Purple!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen.fill(WHITE)

pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,[100,100,sizex-199,sizey-199],2)

pygame.display.flip()

#Draw the grid.
for x in range(length):
    pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,[(x*space+100),100],[(x*space+100),sizey-100],2)        #Vertical lines.
for x in range(width):
    pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,[100,(x*space+100)],[sizex-100,(x*space+100)],2)        #Horizontal lines.

pygame.display.flip()

place = [[0 for y in range(width)] for x in range(length)]
wall = [[[1 for z in range(4)] for y in range(width)] for x in range(length)]
#If wall is [0,1,2,3], 0:up 1:down 2:left 3:right.

i=0
j=0
place[i][j]=1

done=False

#Randomly generates the maze.
while not done:

    sumcheck=0

    newplace=0

    direction = random.randint(0,3) #0:up 1:down 2:left 3:right.
    if direction==0:
        if j!=0:
            if place[i][j-1]==0:
                pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE,[space*i+102,space*j+100],[space*i+99+space,space*j+100],2)
                wall[i][j][0]=0
                j=j-1
                place[i][j]=1
                wall[i][j][1]=0
    elif direction==1:
        if j!=width-1:
            if place[i][j+1]==0:
                pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE,[space*i+102,space*j+100+space],[space*i+99+space,space*j+100+space],2)
                wall[i][j][1]=0
                j=j+1
                place[i][j]=1
                wall[i][j][0]=0
    elif direction==2:
        if i!=0:
            if place[i-1][j]==0:
                pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE,[space*i+100,space*j+102],[space*i+100,space*j+99+space],2)
                wall[i][j][2]=0
                i=i-1
                place[i][j]=1
                wall[i][j][3]=0
    else:
        if i!=length-1:
            if place[i+1][j]==0:
                pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE,[space*i+100+space,space*j+102],[space*i+100+space,space*j+99+space],2)
                wall[i][j][3]=0
                i=i+1
                place[i][j]=1
                wall[i][j][2]=0

    #These statements test if place is stuck.
    if (i==0) and (j==0):
        if (place[i+1][j]==1) and (place[i][j+1]==1):
            #Top left corner
            newplace=1
    elif (i==length-1) and (j==0):
        if (place[i-1][j]==1) and (place[i][j+1]==1):
            #Top right corner
            newplace=1
    elif (i==0) and (j==width-1):
        if (place[i][j-1]==1) and (place[i+1][j]==1):
            #Bottom left corner
            newplace=1
    elif (i==length-1) and (j==width-1):
        if (place[i][j-1]==1) and (place[i-1][j]==1):
            #Bottom right corner
            newplace=1
    elif (i==0) and (place[i][j-1]==1):
        if (place[i+1][j]==1) and (place[i][j+1]==1):
            #Left edge
            newplace=1
    elif (i==length-1):
        if (place[i][j-1]==1) and (place[i-1][j]==1) and (place[i][j+1]==1):
            #Right edge
            newplace=1
    elif (j==width-1):
        if (place[i-1][j]==1) and (place[i][j-1]==1) and (place[i+1][j]==1):
            #Top edge
            newplace=1
    elif (j==0):
        if (place[i-1][j]==1) and (place[i][j+1]==1) and (place[i+1][j]==1):
            #Bottom edge
            newplace=1
    elif (i!=0) and (j!=0) and (i!=length-1) and (j!=width-1):
        if (place[i][j-1]==1) and (place[i][j+1]==1) and (place[i-1][j]==1) and (place[i+1][j]==1):
            #Everything in between
            newplace=1
    else:
        pass


    #If stuck, find a new place.
    donemini = False
    if newplace==1:
        while not donemini:
            i=random.randint(0,length-1)
            j=random.randint(0,width-1)
            if place[i][j]!=1:
                pass
            else:
                donemini=True

    pygame.display.flip()

    for x in range(length):
        for y in range(width):
            sumcheck=sumcheck+place[x][y]
    pygame.display.set_caption("Progress: "+str((int(sumcheck/(width*length)*1000))/10)+"% (Might take a while for bigger mazes)")
    if sumcheck==width*length:
        done=True


i=0
j=0
pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)

i=length-1
j=width-1
pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)

pygame.display.set_caption("Make Purple!")

pygame.display.flip()
done = False

i=0
j=0

win=0

escape=False

#Controlls the block through the maze.
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if (i==length-1) and (j==width-1):
            win=1
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,PURPLE,[102+(length-1)*space,102+(width-1)*space,space-2,space-2],0)
            print("Congradulations, you solved the maze!")
            done=True

        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            done=True

        #0:up 1:down 2:left 3:right.
        if win==0:
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                direction=-1
                if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                    direction=0
                elif event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                    direction=1
                elif event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                    direction=2
                elif event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    direction=3
                elif event.key==pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    direction=4
                else:
                    pass

                if direction==0:
                    if wall[i][j][0]==0:
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                        j=j-1
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                elif direction==1:
                    if wall[i][j][1]==0:
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                        j=j+1
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                elif direction==2:
                    if wall[i][j][2]==0:
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                        i=i-1
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                elif direction==3:
                    if wall[i][j][3]==0:
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                        i=i+1
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                elif direction==4:
                    #Automatically solve the maze.
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)

                    i=0
                    j=0
                    solved=False
                    past=4
                    color=[[0 for y in range(width)] for x in range(length)]
                    newcolor=0

                    while not solved:
                        newcolor=0
                        #0:up 1:down 2:left 3:right.
                        direction=random.randint(0,3)

                        if direction==0:
                            if wall[i][j][0]==0:
                                if past==1:
                                    pass
                                else:
                                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,LRED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                                    j=j-1
                                    color[i][j]=1
                                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                                    past=0
                        elif direction==1:
                            if wall[i][j][1]==0:
                                if past==0:
                                    pass
                                else:
                                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,LRED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                                    j=j+1
                                    color[i][j]=1
                                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                                    past=1
                        elif direction==2:
                            if wall[i][j][2]==0:
                                if past==3:
                                    pass
                                else:
                                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,LRED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                                    i=i-1
                                    color[i][j]=1
                                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                                    past=2
                        else:
                            if wall[i][j][3]==0:
                                if past==2:
                                    pass
                                else:
                                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,LRED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                                    i=i+1
                                    color[i][j]=1
                                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                                    past=3

                        if (i==length-1) and (j==width-1):
                            solved=True
                            i=0
                            j=0
                            pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                            i=length-1
                            j=width-1
                            pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                            i=0
                            j=0

                        elif ((wall[i][j][0]==1) and (wall[i][j][2]==1) and (wall[i][j][3]==1)) or ((wall[i][j][1]==1) and (wall[i][j][2]==1) and (wall[i][j][3]==1)) or ((wall[i][j][0]==1) and (wall[i][j][1]==1) and (wall[i][j][2]==1)) or ((wall[i][j][0]==1) and (wall[i][j][1]==1) and (wall[i][j][3]==1)):                 
                            newcolor=1

                        if newcolor==1:
                            for i in range(length):
                                for j in range(width):
                                    if color[i][j]==1:
                                        pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
                            i=0
                            j=0

                        pygame.display.flip()
                else:
                    pass

        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(120)

time.sleep(2)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried backtracking? (combination of recursive and iterative), it should be a lot faster than choosing random directions.

Comment: I could make it so that if it is stuck it could go back one step, i'll try that. But what if it just goes to the incorrect branch? Backtracking then wouldn't help much.

Comment: Wow, i forgot to reinitialize the `past` variable when it it is stuck. If I edit it, eventually it will randomly stumble across the correct route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a backtracking approach that will find the solution much faster than the random one:

```
import itertools
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

def solve(i, j, wall, steps, solution):
    if i<0 or i>=length or j<0 or j>=width:
        return   # rejected

    # Accepted
    steps.append( (i,j) )

    # Check if solved
    if (i==length-1) and (j==width-1):  
        solution += steps   # fill solution list with the steps list
        return

    # Iterate over options
    for direction in range(0,4):

        if wall[i][j][direction]:
            pass        # rejected - wall
        else:
            if direction == 0:
                next = i, j-1
            elif direction == 1:
                next = i, j+1
            elif direction == 2:
                next = i-1, j
            elif direction == 3:
                next = i+1, j

            if next in steps:
                pass        # rejected (already visited)
            else:
                solve(next[0],next[1],wall,steps,solution)
                if solution:
                    return
                else:
                    steps.pop() # remove last attempt

def solve_and_paint(i,j,screen,clock,wall,color):

    #Automatically solve the maze.
    solution = []
    solve(i, j, wall, [], solution)

    print solution

    for i,j in solution:
        color[i][j]=1
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
        clock.tick(10)   # show slowly
        pygame.display.flip()

        # Return color to light red
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,LRED,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)
```

Put the code after generating the map and before the main loop, just before initializing `i` and `j`.

Then call `solve_and_paint()` when you want to solve it:

```
            elif direction==4:
                #Automatically solve the maze.
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,[102+i*space,102+j*space,space-2,space-2],0)

                i=0
                j=0
                color=[[0 for y in range(width)] for x in range(length)]
                solve_and_paint(i,j,screen,clock,wall,color)
```

Comment: You are welcome. Also, in the loops where you don't process events (generate and solve), you can `pygame.event.poll()` to avoid getting a stuck/blank screen.

Comment: Sorry, `pygame.event.poll()` is valid and works but only processes one event per iteration, the correct way is `pygame.event.pump()`, as it processes *all* the pending events at once.